# 'man robocopy' doesn't work in Powershell console

Tags: powershell

When I type `man robocopy` in powershell it shows:

> Get-Help : Get-Help could not find robocopy in a help file in this session.
>   To download updated help topics type:"Update-Help".

I ran `Update-Help` in powershell as admin, it downloaded help for different modules. But still it shows same error for `man robocopy`.

It works for other command like `man dir`

Comment: `man` is an alias for the cmdlet `Get-Help`; hence the behavior you are seeing. What is `man` in your context?

Comment: `robocopy` is not a PowerShell cmdlet but a tool supplied with Windows, and so PowerShell has no separate help on it. Use `robocopy /?`. To find out if a command is a cmdlet or an application, use `Get-Command`.

Comment: `Get-Alias man`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In PowerShell `man` is an Alias of `Get-Help`. And `dir` is an alias of `Get-ChildItem`. So `man dir` works because really its just doing `Get-Help Get-ChildItem`.

You can't do `man Robocopy` because Robocopy is an external executable and not a PowerShell command, so there's no PowerShell help content for it.

You need to do `Robocopy /?`.